# Merge a two dictionaries based on keys with no duplicates

Tags: python, json, dictionary, merge

Dict 1 :

> {'result2': [{'2': '22'}, {'22': '222'}], 'result1': [{'1': '11'}, {'11': '111'}]}

Dict  2:

> {'result2': [{'two': 'twentytwo'}, {'22': '222'}], 'result1': [{'one': 'eleven'}, {'11': '111'}]}

I want to merge them based on keys result1 and result 2 and preserve the same format.

Expected Output

```
{"result1":[{"1":"11"},{"one":"eleven"},{"11":"111"}]},{"result2":[{"2":"22"},{"two":"twentytwo"},{"22":"222"}]}
```

And the keys of both dict may not necessarily have same index.

Comment: What would be the output?

Comment: First, present the desired output.
Second, what do you mean by merge? Do you want to turn the string into integers?

Comment: updated the output @eh329

Answer (score 2):

It's always good to add desired format for output. It likes you want to list of dict which contains data from both  with respect to result1 & result 2.

Given -

```
a = [{"result1":[{"1":"11"},{"11":"111"}]},{"result2":[{"2":"22"},{"22":"222"}]}]
b = [{"result1":[{"one":"eleven"},{"11":"111"}]},{"result2":[{"two":"twentytwo"},{"22":"222"}]}]
```

Here is code-

```
desired_op = []
for index, item in enumerate(a):
   inner_item = {}
   for key, value in item.items():
     #print (key, value + b[index][key])
     inner_item[key] = value + b[index][key]
   desired_op.append(inner_item)
 
print (desired_op)
[{'result1': [{'1': '11'}, {'11': '111'}, {'one': 'eleven'}, {'11': '111'}]}, {'result2': [{'2': '22'}, {'22': '222'}, {'two': 'twentytwo'}, {'22': '222'}]}]
```

If you need unique items, it will be bit complex-

```
desired_op = []
 for index, item in enumerate(a):
   inner_item = {}
   for key, value in item.items():
     #print (key, value + b[index][key])
     inner_item[key] = list({list(litem.keys())[0]:litem for litem in value + b[index][key]}.values())
   desired_op.append(inner_item)
 
print (desired_op)
[{'result1': [{'1': '11'}, {'11': '111'}, {'one': 'eleven'}]}, {'result2': [{'2': '22'}, {'22': '222'}, {'two': 'twentytwo'}]}]
```

### follow up on comment

simple append can work, but for this you must be sure that first index from second list should contain result1 & second index should contain result2 as dict keys.

ex. (but this won't remove duplicates)

```
a[0]['result1'].extend(b[0]['result1'])
a[1]['result2'].extend(b[1]['result2'])
print(a)
[{'result1': [{'1': '11'}, {'11': '111'}, {'one': 'eleven'}, {'11': '111'}]}, {'result2': [{'2': '22'}, {'22': '222'}, {'two': 'twentytwo'}, {'22': '222'}]}]
```

if you aren't sure about index position in second list, this will work-

```
keys_mapping =  {list(item.keys())[0]:index for index, item in enumerate(a)}
print (keys_mapping)
{'result1': 0, 'result2': 1}

for item in b:
  key = list(item.keys())[0]
  a[keys_mapping[key]][key].extend(item[key])
print (a)
[{'result1': [{'1': '11'}, {'11': '111'}, [{'one': 'eleven'}, {'11': '111'}]]}, {'result2': [{'2': '22'}, {'22': '222'}, [{'two': 'twentytwo'}, {'22': '222'}]]}]
```

Comment: Any chance of using update() function of dictionary to simplify it?

Comment: And the index of both dict may not necessarily have same keys.

Comment: if you are sure about format, index & keys. simple append can work. updating answer

Comment: simplified the question. would be great if you have a look at it

Comment: @regretter in this case `a['result2'].extend(b['result2'])  a['result1'].extend(b['result1'])` will work but duplicate will stay same `{'result2': [{'2': '22'}, {'22': '222'}, {'two': 'twentytwo'}, {'22': '222'}], 'result1': [{'1': '11'}, {'11': '111'}, {'one': 'eleven'}, {'11': '111'}]}`

Comment: if you modify your input like this `a = {'result2': {'2': '22', '22': '222'}, 'result1': {'1': '11', '11': '111'}}
b = {'result2': {'two': 'twentytwo', '22': '222'}, 'result1': {'one': 'eleven', '11': '111'}}` your solution will be
`a['result2'].update(b['result2'])
a['result1'].update(b['result1'])
print (a)
{'result2': {'2': '22', '22': '222', 'two': 'twentytwo'}, 'result1': {'1': '11', '11': '111', 'one': 'eleven'}}`

Answer (score 0):

You could separate this in two phases:

1. merge the dictionaries by appending the lists
2. remove duplicates from the resulting merged dictionary

...

```
dict1={'result2': [{'2': '22'}, {'22': '222'}], 
       'result1': [{'1': '11'}, {'11': '111'}]}
dict2={'result2': [{'two': 'twentytwo'}, {'22': '222'}], 
       'result1': [{'one': 'eleven'}, {'11': '111'}]}

# merge phase
dict3 = {k:dict1.get(k,[])+dict2.get(k,[]) for k in {*dict1,*dict2}}
        
# uniqueness phase
dict3 = {k:[d for i,d in enumerate(v) if v.index(d)==i] 
         for k,v in dict3.items()}
    
print(dict3)

{'result2': [{'2': '22'}, {'22': '222'}, {'two': 'twentytwo'}],
 'result1': [{'1': '11'}, {'11': '111'}, {'one': 'eleven'}]}
```

Note that you could combine the two phases in one large dictionary comprehension:

```
dict3 = {k: [d for i,d in enumerate(v) if v.index(d)==i]
         for k in {*dict1,*dict2}
         for v in [dict1.get(k,[])+dict2.get(k,[])] }
```

If dict1 and dict2 are guaranteed to have the same keys, then the whole process can be performed more concisely:

```
dict3 = {k:v+[w for w in dict2[k] if w not in v] for k,v in dict1.items()}
```